# Getting XMLPullParserException Expected END_TAG while Connecting to the WCF from Android

Tags: android

I need to connect to the WCF webservices from my android app for login authentication, for that, i have added **ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar** to my project.
Here is my code below.

```
String emailtxt = null, password;

    emailtxt = email.getText().toString().trim();
    password = pwd.getText().toString().trim();

    Log.d("email", emailtxt);
    Log.d("password", password);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    /*request.addProperty("arg0", emailtxt);
    request.addProperty("arg1", password);*/


    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("UserName");
    pi.setValue(emailtxt);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    PropertyInfo pi2 = new PropertyInfo();
    pi2.setName("Password");
    pi2.setValue(password);
    pi2.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi2);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
    httpTransport.debug = true;
    SoapObject result = null;
    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (result == null)
        Log.d("if resp null", result + "");
    else {
        // anything below this line relates to the service return type, may
        // not apply to you
        boolean success = Boolean.valueOf(result.getProperty("success")
                .toString());

        Log.d("login resp...not null", success + "");
    }
```

But iam getting XMLPullParserException in my logcat.Can any one tell me how to fix it?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using XMLPUllParser to parse the XML file.?

Comment: Thanks for replay Droid.iam not using the XMLPullParser and getting the  org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: END_TAG.

Comment: try this    result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn; instead    result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

Comment: i tried it,but no luck.